# How do I validate the name of files uploaded using yup and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

```
const SUPPORTED_NAMES = ['Account', 'Location', 'SS'];

const validationSchema = yup.object({
  files: yup
    .mixed()
    .test('required', 'You need to provide a file', (value) => {
      if (value.length > 0) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    })
    .test(
      'fileName',
      'Unsupported name',
      (value) => value && SUPPORTED_NAMES.includes(value.name)
    ),
});
```

The issue I have now is that my validation is not supporting any file name. I want to be able to only upload files that includes the values from SUPPORTED_NAMES and be able to submit it.

Comment: Is `files` an array?

Comment: You have checked value.length in first test, So the value must be containing Array. 
So for checking the value.name will give undefined. 
You can write like value.filter(name=>SUPPERTED_NAMES.includes(name)).length===value.length
.This will show error if any of the files does not match supported names.
Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: yes, files is an array. I'll try this: value.filter(name=>SUPPERTED_NAMES.includes(name)).length===value.length thank you

Comment: @Avkash that didn't work for me. I was able to find the answer base on your response. Thank you