# how to validate a file name match a criteria in react yup

Tags: reactjs, yup

I want to validate that my file names include the SUPPORTED_NAMES. If I upload a file without the account in its name it should not pass validation. right now my code does not pass validation no matter the name of the file

```
const SUPPORTED_NAMES = ['Account','ticket','task']

validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
  file: Yup.mixed()
    .required("file is required")
    .test(
      "fileName",
      "file name not supported",
      (value) => value && SUPPORTED_NAMES.includes(value.name)
    )
```

Comment: The code you have works fine for me. If you checkout this Code Sandbox below you can see a working example with almost identical code but manually invoking the validation. It may have something to do with how you're passing your `validationSchema` but I'm not sure without seeing the rest of your code.


  [1]: https://codesandbox.io/s/yup-forked-frmmsg?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I see. I need to check why is not validating for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: In most case, file must be containing an Array, If it is an array, You can write like value.filter(name=>SUPPERTED_NAMES.includes(name)).length===value.length .This will show error if any of the files does not match supported names. Let me know if this works for you! This should also works for multiple file upload.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73716894/how-do-i-validate-the-name-of-files-uploaded-using-yup-and-react . Here's the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with the answer:

```
test('fileName', 'unsuported file name', (value: FileList)=>{
   for(let i = 0; i < value.lenght; i++){
   const file = value.item(i);
   if(file.name){
    const hasKeyWord = SUPPORTED_NAMES.some((element) => 
     file.name.includes(element.toLowerCase())
   );
     if(!hasKeyWord){
      return false
    }
  }
}
 return true;

})
```